# Cancel android notification when a user access a web page in a web site

Tags: android, web, notifications

Just that, like facebook or gmail does, what I need is to cancel a notification from the web site.

Thks.

Answer (score 0):

The website updates its internal database, then either issues a GCM push or waits for the next time the app polls it to send the new data. Then the app will process the push or poll.  The app then figures out what the notification should be and cancels it if necessary.